Как растянуть текстуру между 4 точками?
Всем привет. Делаю 3D-проекцию, не спрашивайте на чём (сам скажу, на Scratch. Хоть и есть другие нормальные языки, да хоть питон или джава, хочу слепить что-то на детской платформе). Так вот, дело дошло до размещения текстуры. Так вот, я ищу формулу, которая бы при введении туда координат относительно 4 точек, между которыми будет текстура выводила бы какой это номер пикселя в текстуре (ну или просто номер пикселя относительно граней). Я уже неделю думаю над этим вопросом. Также, следует учесть, что 4 точки, между которыми будет находиться текстура, стоят понятное дело в разнобой.

Двоичным поиском можно обратить билинейную интерполяцию. Как проще - не знаю.
